# how to get all the keywords searched by users on google to come to your website through google analytics v4?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-4

I want to get keywords listing that users searched through google search.
To track the keywords searched by users on Google and have them appear in your website's Google Analytics (GA) data, you'll need to set up Google Search Console and link it to your GA account.
Lisiting of keywords date wise or time wise

Answer (score 0):

As google Analytics 4 dont give you this functionality to get keywords searched by users you can achieve this by google search console. here is the api in node js.
also please note that you should have client_id client_email ,private_key and project id into your json file.

const path = require('path');
const credentialsPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'plastk-387013-af6d7ec91f42.json');

app.get('/getKeywords,async (req, res) => {

```
try {
    const authClient = await google.auth.getClient({
        keyFile: credentialsPath,
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly'],
    });
    const searchConsole = google.webmasters({
        version: 'v3',
        auth: authClient,
    });
    const request = {
        siteUrl: 'Your-Website-Url',
        requestBody: {
            startDate: '2023-05-10',
            endDate: '2023-05-29',
            dimensions: ['query'],
        },
    };
    const response = await searchConsole.searchanalytics.query(request);
    const keywords = response.data.rows.map(row => row.keys[0]);
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'success', data: keywords });
} catch (error) {`enter code here`
    console.error('Error :', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred' });
}
```

};